# Oracle-Apex Tree more than three layers

Tags: sql, tree, oracle-apex

I´ve got the following sql code to generate a tree in APEX:

```
select 1 as status, 1 pid, 'Fehlermeldungen' as titel, null as icon, '1' as value, NULL as tooltip, NULL as link from dual
union
select -1 as status, 2 pid, k.kname as titel, NULL as icon, k.knr||'0' as value, NULL as tooltip, NULL as link from kunde k where 
(select count(fmtext) from fehlermeldung f where f.knr = k.knr) > 0
union
select 0 as status, 3 pid, fmtext as titel, NULL as icon, k.knr||fmnr as value, NULL as tooltip, null as link from kunde k, fehlermeldung f where f.knr = k.knr
order by value
```

Now, I want to add a fourth layer but if I try to make another union with pid = 4, the entry attaches to the last select. 
How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1):

First, I tried reformatting your code a little. It seems that what you are describing should work fine. I assume you tried something like this:

```
select 1 as status, 1 pid, 'Fehlermeldungen' as titel, null as icon, '1' as value, 
       NULL as tooltip, NULL as link from dual
union
select -1 as status, 2 pid, k.kname as titel, NULL as icon, k.knr||'0' as value, 
       NULL as tooltip, NULL as link from kunde k 
where (select count(fmtext) from fehlermeldung f where f.knr = k.knr) > 0
union
select 0 as status, 3 pid, fmtext as titel, NULL as icon, k.knr||fmnr as value, 
       NULL as tooltip, null as link from kunde k, fehlermeldung f 
where f.knr = k.knr
-- begin my new lines...
union
select 0 as status, 4 pid, 'blank' as titel, NULL as icon, '4' as value, 
       NULL as tooltip, null as link from dual 
-- end my new lines...
order by 5
```

Is it possible you inserted the additional SELECT in the wrong place? Show us what you did and it will be easier to troubleshoot.